# How to add widget to gridlayout starting from top-left corner

Tags: python, layout, pyqt

I have created a UI in Qt Designer and converted it to python:

[image]

In the empty area I added a scrollarea and a gridlayout to align my buttons.

Each time I press the "CreatePose" Button, I need to add a pushbutton with an icon to gridlayout, starting at the top-left corner. Right now it adds it at center of the gridlayout.

```
self.ui.PoseBtn_GridLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(4,4)
self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('')
self.button.setIcon(self._icon)
self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
self.button.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
self.button.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
self.ui.PoseBtn_GridLayout.addWidget(self.button)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: that's for what `QSpacerItem`s are for, it's occupying the center because it is the only widget in your layout

Comment: Checkout [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13953945/1006989), I modified it to display `QPushButton`'s in grid layout without overlapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if replacing the code you posted with this works for you:

```
self.ui.PoseBtn_GridLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(4,4)

spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
self.ui.PoseBtn_GridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 1, 1, 1, 1)

spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
self.ui.PoseBtn_GridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)

self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('')
self.button.setIcon(self._icon)
self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
self.button.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
self.button.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
self.ui.PoseBtn_GridLayout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

*EDIT*

This is how your should display your widgets to get the expected results, checkout the *Object Inspector*, basically you need a `QWidget` with grid layout inside another `QWidget` with also grid layout and 2 `QSpaceItem`'s:

[image: Qt Designer Screenshot]

Comment: ya its working but if i create another button by clicking createpose btn.. then my second overlapping the first btn

Comment: How to delete all my widgets inside my grid widgets and recreate that all widgets in same order.. like refreshing my buttons if i add one more on it..

Comment: @rishis3d I can help you with that, please start a new post and mention me in a comment so I get notified

Comment: Hi jacobs.. here i started a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003652/how-to-delete-all-widgets-inside-a-gridlayout-widgets-and-recreate-that-all-widg