# How to delete all widgets inside a gridlayout widgets and recreate that all widgets in same order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

this is continuation of my previous question in here.. **"How to add widget to gridlayout starting from top-left corner"** thanks to  **X.Jacobs** to fix tat issue.. 
Now  i want to delete all that widgets and recreate that same widgets in same order, like refreshing a widget library..
thanks

[image]

ok this is my ui.. when i click the createPose button it will call 3 Def..

**1**. create a txt file in a specific folder

**2**. clear all my widgets in my grid layout...

**3**. and finally recreate my all widgets based on number of files and filenames in tat specific folder like adding a widget and refreshing the Library.. but in a same order like it previously where it was..

```py
        self.connect(self.ui.CreatePose_pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.createPose)

    def createPose(self):
                # To get Posename from UI
        self.__current_Posename = self.getPoseName()

        Path = 'D:\\PoseLibrary\\'

                # To Grab All files in tat Path
        Poses = self.findAllFiles(Path, '.xml')

        self.__NameSpace = self.ui.NameSpace_comboBox.currentText()

                #To find HighestTrailingNumber to Increment the file name
        if self.__current_Posename == "":
            newSuffix = self.findHighestTrailingNumber(Poses, self.__Default_Posename) + 1
            self.PoseName = self.__Default_Posename + str(newSuffix)
        else:
            self.PoseName = self.__current_Posename


        # Creating XML and Icon files
        open(Path + self.PoseName  + '.xml','w').close()

        icon = self.createIcon(self.PoseName, Path)
        # open(Path + self.PoseName  + '.png','w').close()


        self.refreshPoseLibrary(Path)
        self.ui.PoseName_lineEdit.clear()



    def refreshPoseLibrary(self, Path ):
        # First Clear all my buttons in gridlayout
                self.deleteAll()

                # get all file fromm the path dir

        Files = self.getfiles_by_Date(Path)
        Poses = self.findAllFiles(Files, '.xml')

                # Create Btn 
        for Pose in Poses:
            icon = Path + Pose + '.png'
            self.icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(icon), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('')
            self.button.setObjectName(Pose)
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.button)
            self.button.setIcon(self.icon)
            self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
            self.button.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
            self.button.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
            self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button)
            self.button.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            self.connect(self.button, QtCore.SIGNAL('customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)'), self.popup)

    def deleteAll(self):
        while self.ui.gridLayout.count():
            item = self.ui.gridLayout.takeAt(0)
            widget = item.widget()
            widget.deleteLater()


        def getfiles_by_Date(self, dirpath):
        Files = [s for s in os.listdir(dirpath)
             if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirpath, s))]
        Files.sort(key=lambda s: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dirpath, s)))
        return Files
```

Now i added one more function to sort my folder files by date of creation .. now my gridlayout arrange my buttons in a correct order.. but position of the button is jumping .. like a gap between them..i have uploaded my screen shot also

Comment: Post a complete question instead of referring to just a title of another and hoping everyone knows the contents of that question.

Comment: Do you want delete them or just hide them? Could you post your code to understand what you are doing?

Comment: still don't understand what is it that you are trying to accomplish by clearing all the widget from the layout, maybe you can call `widget.hide()` and then `widget.show()` or `widget.setVisible(False)` and `widget.setVisible(True)` when you are done... there's no real need to see an image of your gui, it would be better if you posted a manageable version of your actual code, please do it

Comment: Not sure if I am getting this right, but I don't think that you can preserve the order of the widgets. If you add the widgets based on files in a directoryA (fileA, fileB, filC), you cannot enter another directoryB (fileX, fileY, fileZ) and expect the exact same order, mostly because the files are different. However, if you want the same order of widgets each time you enter *the same* directory, you can sort the filenames before creating the widgets, that is `for Pose in list(sorted(Poses))`

Comment: Now i added one more function to sort my folder files by date of creation .. now my gridlayout arrange my buttons in a correct order.. but position of the button is jumping .. like a gap between them..

Answer (score 4):

Deleting all widgets from a layout looks like this:

```py
while layout.count():
    item = layout.takeAt(0)
    widget = item.widget()
    # if widget has some id attributes you need to
    # save in a list to maintain order, you can do that here
    # i.e.:   aList.append(widget.someId)
    if widget is not None: 
        widget.deleteLater()
```